# How to prevent text inside a div from affecting the spacing around div

Tags: html, css

```html
<style>
  #main {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
  }

  #main div {
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>

<div id='main'>
  <div>x</div>
  <div>x</div>
  <div>x</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I have a grid of divs set up just a like a checker board. The divs are either empty, or have a single unicode character inside of them.

When a character is removed from or added to the div, the spacing around the div is affected. (see snippet)

How can I stop this behavior? I would like for the content inside of the div to not affect the positioning or spacing around the div.

Comment: you could add &nbsp; to the div where you don't have an input. Flex is a better way to go although that doesn't answer the question as to why this happens.  perhaps someone else has an answer

Comment: again, none of the answers explain why the behavior is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can fix your code by adding vertical-align:top to your inner 4 divs

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the display:inline-block, try with display:flex on the outer div.
[Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because of the way that [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is calculated. When no `vertical-align` is set, the default is `baseline`. However, when there is no text, `baseline` is calculated differently. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24862926/4713952).

Using FlexBox, as suggested by most of the other answers would obviously avoid this issue.

If you want to avoid FlexBox, probably the best option is to just set `vertical-align` explicitly, as suggested in [DCR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69700720/4713952).

Another method would be to wrap the inner text in a `<span>` and add `position: absolute`. This way, all the boxes effectively have the same size content, and the discrepancy is resolved. Here's an example:

```html
<style>
#main {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}

#main div {
  position:relative;
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#main div span {
  position: absolute
}
</style>

<div id='main'>
  <div><span>x</span></div>
  <div><span>x</span></div>
  <div><span>x</span></div>
  <div><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like Nicola Revelant said in their answer, you can use something like flexbox to make this work. Here's an example:

```html
    <style>
      #main {
        width: 110px;
        height: 110px;
        display: flex;
      }

      #main div {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      
      #main div div {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: solid 1px black;
      }
    </style>

    <div id='main'>
      <div class="row1">
        <div>x</div>
        <div>x</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row2">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```